# При удалении элементов поочередно удаляется только один

Tags: javascript

```
let deleteProfile = document.querySelector('.profile')
let cross = document.querySelectorAll('.profile__delete')

for (let element of cross) {
    element.onclick = () => deleteProfile.remove()
}

<section class="list">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="list__inner">
            @foreach ($data as $element)
            <div class="profile">
                <ul>
                    <li class="profile__fild">
                        <div class="profile__number">{{ $element->id }}</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="profile__name">{{ $element->name }}</li>
                    <li class="profile__city">{{ $element->city }}</li>
                    <li class="profile__age">{{ $element->age }}</li>
                    <li class="profile__specialty">{{ $element->specialty }}</li>
                    <li><a class="profile__write" href="#">Написать</a></li>
                    <li><a class="profile__call" href="#">Позвонить</a></li>
                    <li><div class="profile__delete"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Потому что `document.querySelector('.profile')` даёт первый елемент. Вам нужно проитерировать все `.profile` либо сделайте как-то так `<div class="profile" onClick="(() => {this.remove(); return false;})()">`

Comment: Проитерировать у меня не получается, а вот это <div class="profile" onClick="(() => {this.remove(); return false;})()">   ПОМОГЛО!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу и Вам нужно удалить конкретный `.profile` элемент по нажатию на вложенный в него `.profile__delete` элемент, то:

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  event.target.closest(".profile").remove()
}

document.querySelectorAll(".profile__delete").forEach(item =>
  item.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="list">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="list__inner">
      <div class="profile">
        <ul>
          <li class="profile__fild">
            <div class="profile__number">Profile 1</div>
          </li>
          <li class="profile__name"></li>
          <li class="profile__city"></li>
          <li class="profile__age"></li>
          <li class="profile__specialty"></li>
          <li><a class="profile__write" href="#">Написать</a></li>
          <li><a class="profile__call" href="#">Позвонить</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="profile__delete">DELETE</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="profile">
        <ul>
          <li class="profile__fild">
            <div class="profile__number">Profile 2</div>
          </li>
          <li class="profile__name"></li>
          <li class="profile__city"></li>
          <li class="profile__age"></li>
          <li class="profile__specialty"></li>
          <li><a class="profile__write" href="#">Написать</a></li>
          <li><a class="profile__call" href="#">Позвонить</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="profile__delete">DELETE</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли, но код не работает((

Comment: app.js:19308 Uncaught TypeError: cross.addEventListener is not a function
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:19308)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:21075)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87

Comment: @kstdbrv поправил, извиняюсь, незаметил ошибку